# Diamond question mark where there should be a space in Neo4j nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV with

```
spell,  ph_spell,
than,   th uh n,
than,   th an,
than,   th en,
that,   th at,
that,   th uh t,
can,    kan,
can,    kuh n,
```

as well as other words. That I am loading into Neo4j.

when I import the CSV. I get

[image]

And

[image]

What I don't understand is why I am get that Diamond question mark where there should be a space.  It is coming in some of the words but others have the space. All words show with the space on notepad and Excess
Also, what can I do about it?

Comment: This seems like a character encoding issue. However, we need more information to determines why it's happening: what exactly is a CVC and how do you import it?

Comment: It is a CVC file I made myself.  Column one is a list of words. Column 2 is the phonetic spelling of the word. The phonetic spelling came from  dictionary.com. I copied and pasted for each word.

Comment: What is a CVC file? It reminds me of the [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Comment: My guess would be that it somehow inserts a different character than space, but your pasted sample contains plain spaces -- I checked with a [hex tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-to-hex) and looked for 20, which is the hex code for spaces. So, how do you load the data?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it is CSV.

Comment: So it's resolved? Feel free to answer your own questions if others can learn from this.